# Skye's origin story

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

As Skye's origin story is revealed, I find myself uncertain about one element in Episode 112: Seeds...

> Coulson reveals that the team that eventually got her to the Orphanage was responding to an 0-8-4 (unknown alien artifact).
>  
>  It is also mentioned that most of the team died to protect Skye, and di some other untoward things, including forging Level 8 credentials in order to hide her.

What I am unclear on: is Skye herself the 0-8-4?

Answer (score 8):

It seems you missed part of the conversation:

> **Lumley**:  "He was still holding on to the 0-8-4.  Poor thing was covered in blood.  We thought she was dead, too.  But.. she was just asleep in the dead agent's arms."
>  
>  **Coulson**:  "Wait.. the baby?  The girl was the 0-8-4?"
>  
>  **Lumley**:  "She had powers or something, we never witnessed it."
>  
>  They go on to explain that they used SHIELD resources to hide the baby, shifting her from foster home to foster home.  The end of the episode makes it clear that the baby is Skye, and the conversation quoted above makes it clear that the baby was also the 0-8-4.
>  
>  Also, an 0-8-4 is an "object of unknown origin", not necessarily alien.

Comment: Was airing during a windstorm - that scene didn't come through intact.

Comment: That's some realistic television kicking up a windstorm IRL right when there's a giant windstorm going on in the show.

Comment: The winds move the trees... which moves them into and out of the LOS to the broadcast antenna.